# How to provide elasticsearch TTL per index document operation?

Tags: elasticsearch

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html seems to indicate that a TTL can be set per query (I'm assuming this means it can be set on a per index operation basis). How is that done?

Is it just a matter of doing something like:

```
client.prepareIndex('index-name', 'type-name')
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field('_ttl', '1d')
                        .field('other-field', 'other-value')
                    .endObject()
                  )
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-ttl indicates that what you have should work.

Comment: You need to enable the `_ttl` field in your mappings as it's disabled by default.